# Why do I need to declare "extern crate core" to use libcore?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

With the core library stabilized in Rust 1.6, the following becomes possible, and I do not need to replace `libcore` with `libstd` any more:

```
//extern crate core; //won't work without this line
extern crate num;

use core::ops::Add;
use num::bigint::{BigInt};

fn main() {
    let mut big = "8705702225074732811211966512111".parse::<BigInt>().unwrap();
    let one = "1".parse::<BigInt>().unwrap();
    big = big.add(&one);
    println!("{:?}", big);
}
```

But there is one thing puzzles me - why do I need to declare "extern crate core;"? As far as I know, `libstd` is meant to be built on top of `libcore`. `libcore` is meant to be OS independent, while the implementation of `libstd` can be OS specific. I never had the need to specify "extern crate std". What also puzzles me is that I do not need to add `libcore` as a dependency in Cargo.toml in the above case, although it is an extern crate.

Is `libcore` the only such case? Is this a temporary thing while the implementation of the language is getting stabilized?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fact everything works in a pretty logical way.

First of all, `libstd` crate is indeed special. Rust compiler knows about it and it injects `extern crate std;` implicitly unless `#![no_std]` attribute is present on the crate root. Additionally it also imports standard prelude in every module of your crate (again, unless `#![no_std]` is present).

Now you can probably see why you have to specify `extern crate core;` while at the same time you don't need to specify `extern crate std;`. You also don't need to specify `core` in `Cargo.toml` because `libcore`, as well as several other libraries (`libcollections`, `liballoc`, `liblibc`, etc.; you can find an up-to-date list [in Rust source directory](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src)) are present in the Rust compiler distribution. There is in fact a desire to allow these libraries to be available through Cargo as well (expressed in form of RFCs), but as of now these libraries are provided with the compiler distribution only.

And finally, remember that Rust crates are independent. Rust ABI is designed in such a way so you can have different versions of the same crate built into the final executable. While it is invalid for one crate to directly depend on multiple versions of the same crate, it is possible that its dependencies transitively depend on different versions of another crate. This is one of the reasons why you always have to explicitly specify dependencies of your crate: if you don't specify that your crate depends on `libcore`, even though `libstd` does depend on `libcore`, `libcore` won't be pulled by your crate automatically if it uses `libstd`.